# Difference between VOICE_CALL and VOICE_COMMUNICATION in MediaRecorder.AudioSource

Tags: android, android-ndk, mediarecorder

I'm  using MediaRecorder `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` and `VOICE_CALL` alternatively for call recording in Android (NDK level).

What are the differences between them? I found they are giving a similar recording result.

I checked another [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_COMMUNICATION) but it doesn't clearly specify the difference.

Could you guys help me to differentiate between both `AudioSources`? And maybe there are other references I missed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VOICE_CALL is the actual call data being sent in a call, up and down (so your side and their side).  VOICE_COMMUNICATION is just the microphone, but with codecs and echo cancellation turned on for good voice quality.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan.
So, both will still record the caller's and callee's voice, right?
VOICE_COMMUNICATION will record not only the call voice, but also the microphone voice as well as I tested out again. Thank you!

Comment: @Rico No, you misread.  VOICE_CALL will get caller and callee during a call.  You'd use that to actually get the active call's audio (or you would if it wasn't a secure setting).  VOICE_COMMUNICATION has nothing to do with an active call.  It uses filters suitable for use in voice communication, but it works outside of an active call, and as such there is no other party to record.  You'd use it if you were creating your own VOIP app, for example.